# Can I run an ipython notebook from R studio

Tags: r, rstudio

I've got an ipython notebook  I would like to run before running analysis in R.

I've set up a code chunk in my R notebook to run ipython as follows

````
```{python, engine = 'path/to/ipython'}

import os #analogous to library().  Executres

os.chdir('path/to/analysis') #analogous to setwd(). Execures

%runDataExtraction.ipynb  #problem here
```
````

Here is the error

```
thon: Classes/Stat Comp  File "/var/folders/_1/hdrhn2y9719c6vnr54tsk2tc0000gn/T/RtmpxWbI79/chunk-coded987fa22c02.", line 6
    %run DataExtraction.ipynb
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

R tells me that there is a syntax error in that last line of code.  The code works fine if run in ipython.  Even a bash chunk tells me something is wrong.

Chunk is

````
```{bash}
cd path/to/analysis

jupyter nbconvert --execute DataExtraction.ipynb
```
````

Error is

```
/var/folders/_1/hdrhn2y9719c6vnr54tsk2tc0000gn/T/RtmpxWbI79/chunk-coded986d89ee10.: line 3: jupyter: command not found
```

This error is particularly weird because the jupyter command definitely works in the command line.

Has anyone else run into similar problems?

EDIT:

Little out of the way, but I run a bash command from ipython, and everything works.

````
```{python, engine.path = 'path/to/ipython'}

import os #analogous to library().  Executres

os.chdir('path/to/analysis') #analogous to setwd(). 

bashCommand = "jupyter nbconvert --execute DataExtraction.ipynb"
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()


```
````

Comment: Not easily. The two IDE's approach the same tasks pretty differently.

Comment: @sconfluentus  Yea, I was afraid of that.

Comment: You might be able to coerce something but I doubt it would be worth the effort. what are you trying to accomplish, edit the post and I will try to find a way to help you accomplish your end goals...

Comment: @sconfluentus little hacky, but I solved it

Comment: Does it run and not hiccup? I have moved my python code over to rMarkdown and it runs beautifully, but I did not get the notebooks to run...

Comment: Oh, I see you converted it, that is fine, I though you meant run it straight...sorry!

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 Sure, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution I came across

````
```{python, engine.path = 'path/to/ipython'}

import os #analogous to library().  Executres

os.chdir('path/to/analysis') #analogous to setwd(). 

bashCommand = "jupyter nbconvert --execute DataExtraction.ipynb"
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()


```
````